# Puma - Rails on linux // Restart when process dies

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, daemon, upstart, puma

Using puma on a rails app; it sometimes dies without any articular reason; also often dies (does not restart after being stopped) when deployed

What would be a good way to monitor if the process died, and restart it right way ?
Being called within a rails app; I'd be useful to have a way to defines it for any apps.
I did not found any useable ways to do it (looked into systemd, other linux daemons… no success)

Thanks if any feedback

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `puma control` to start/stop puma server. If you know where `puma.pid` file placed (for Mac it's usually `"#{Dir.pwd}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"`) you could do:

```
bundle exec pumactl -P path/puma.pid stop
```

To set pid file path or to other options (like daemonizing) you could create puma config. You can found [an example here](http://wagn.org/Puma_and_Nginx_production_stack). And then start and stop server just with config file:

```
bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb start
```

You can also restart and check status in this way:

```
bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb restart
bundle exec pumactl -F config/puma.rb status
```

Comment: bingo! added to favorites